# rootless docker - communication between docker containers of different users

Tags: mongodb, docker

When using rootless Docker, Docker instances are running per user and not system-wide. How can I enable communication between Docker containers that have been started by different users?

Scenario is the following. The systems is setup with rootless Docker because multiple people are sharing the same workstation. Rootless Docker is used, so that users building their Docker images and running their containers will not interfer each other.

We also like to run a mongodb in a Docker container, that should be accessible for all users. How can this be done without system-wide Docker? We will be connected to the workstation via ssh and do not want to access the mongodb Docker container from outside the workstation (not being connected via ssh).

Using system-wide Docker is not an option.

Any suggestions how this can be done with root-less Docker?

Info:
Previously with the system-wide Docker we created a network (bridge) and used `docker run --network=some_network_for_mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 mongodb:5.0.2`

Answer (score 2):

> When using rootless Docker, Docker instances are running per user and not system-wide. How can I enable communication between Docker containers that have been started by different users?

The only way you'll be able to enable communication between containers started by different users is by publishing the necessary ports on the host. For example, if you want to create a MongoDB instance that's generally accessible, you could run:

```
docker run -p 27019:27019 ...
```

This binds port 27019 in the mongo container to port 27019 on the host. Any other container on the system would be able to connect to this service using an ip address of a host interface.

Of course, this will also open the port to outside connections. There are several ways of dealing with this:

- Block the port in your firewall configuration.
- Bind the port to a *specific* host interface on which it won't be available for outside access. For example, if you have a docker bridge `docker0` at `172.17.0.1`, you could run:

  ```
  docker run -p 172.17.0.1:27019:27019 ...
  ```

  This would only publish the port on `172.17.0.1`. Other containers could access the service at `172.17.0.1:27019`, but it wouldn't be available for outside access.

Comment: How can I create the docker bridge at a specified IP address?

Comment: I wouldn't do that; I was only suggesting using the docker bridge ip because I figured you already had a `docker0` bridge. If you don't, or if you need a static address, I would suggest creating an interface specifically for this purpose (i.e, acting as the target for binds). You can create a new bridge interface for example, using whatever facilities your distribution provides for configuring persistent interface configurations.

Comment: Wouldn't just binding to 127.0.0.1:27019 be the easiest way to avoid outside access? Everyone on the machine could connect to that port, though.